# How to make comment field in post in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add comment in post in simply ruby on rails application.

Comment: I am new in ruby i have a post and want to add comment in post.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

My Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
    def create
        binding.pry
        @adventure = Adventure.find(params[:adventure_id])
        @comment = @adventure.comments.create(comment_params)

        if @comment.save
            flash[:notice] = "Comment has been created."
            redirect_to @adventure
        else
            flash.now[:danger] = "error"
        end
    end  
      def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end  
end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :adventure
end
```

Comment: You don't need that `binding.pry` there :)

Comment: Also, you meant to use `comments.new` rather than `comments.create`